# Inconsistent display on IE & Firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using `Bootstrap` on my website project. I'm through with the design but the items are displayed out of place on **IE** & **Firefox**. The same page renders great on **Chrome**.

I used developer tools on the three browsers to make sure there was no difference in the CSS properties.

Using developer tools I then tweaked the width of the div to > `33%` to see it being rendered properly in 2 column format on all browsers. Originally the div derives the width `25%` using `.col-sm-3` from `bootstrap.min.css`.

Can anybody suggest any fix for displaying four items in a row as desired? The screenshots from each of the browsers follow -

[image: IE Render]
[image: Firefox Render]
[image: Chrome Render]

And the code -

**HTML Markup**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Project Name</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project Name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Categories<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li><a href="">Nav item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
            <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">More navigation</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
            <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
<!--            <h3 class="page-header">Patterns <small>Please make a selection from the below options</small></h3>-->
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
              <li class="active">Patterns</li>
            </ol>            

          <div class="row placeholders">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="images/desk_138_large.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Pattern 1</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="images/DSF9649_large.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Pattern 2</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="images/GersTable_0011_large.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Pattern 3</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="images/GrandT_0004_large.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Pattern 4</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="images/GrandT_0004_large.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Pattern 4</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>              
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="images/GrandT_0004_large.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Pattern 4</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>              
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="images/GrandT_0004_large.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Pattern 4</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>              
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="images/GrandT_0004_large.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Pattern 4</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>              
            </div>              
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="text-muted">&copy; 2015 -  All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/core.js"></script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

And the **CSS**

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

/*
 * Global add-ons
 */

.sub-header {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

/*
 * Sidebar
 */

/* Hide for mobile, show later */
.sidebar {
    display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .sidebar {
        position: fixed;
        top: 51px;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 10;
        display: block;
        padding: 20px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    }
}

/* Sidebar navigation */
.nav-sidebar {
    margin-right: -21px; /* 20px padding + 1px border */
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
.nav-sidebar > li > a {
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.nav-sidebar > .active > a,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:hover,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #428bca;
}


/*
 * Main content
 */

.main {
    padding: 20px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .main {
        padding-right: 40px;
        padding-left: 40px;
    }
}
.main .page-header {
    margin-top: 0;
}


/*
 * Placeholder dashboard ideas
 */

.placeholders {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.placeholders h4 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.placeholder {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.placeholder img {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10%;
}

/* Footer display CSS */

.footer{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background-color:rgba(245,245,245, 0.9);
    z-index: 20;
}

.container .text-muted{
    margin:20px 0
}

.footer>.container{
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-left:15px
}
```

For what its worth - I'm using IE 11, Firefox 38.0.5, Chrome 43 (64-bit) on Win8.1. Can anybody please suggest a possible fix for this?

**EDIT:** Adding `<div class="clearfix"></div>` fixed the issue. I added it after the four items of the first row.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is necessary but you might consider using some sort of [reset css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). It might fix your cross browser issues

Comment: Try using the latest bootstrap css, I tested this in Firefox & IE, works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/k1k0tzmw/

Comment: I'm actually using Bootstrap v3.3.4 right now. I'll try with v3.3.5 from Bootstrap

Comment: Alright, I switched the links for Bootstrap css and js to the Bootstrap CDN links and no luck. Chrome still manages to display correctly unlike IE & Firefox

Comment: It strikes me that if FF and IE are behaving the same and Chrome is different then it's Chrome that is behaving inconsistently, not FF and IE. Therefore, maybe try tackling the problem from the other direction and try to get Chrome to work the same as the others rather than the other way round. Finally, can you provide a functional demo? It might help us pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Try adding `clearfix` divs as explained in http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

Comment: Great! Adding `<div class="clearfix"></div>` fixed the issue. Can you please add that as an answer?

Edit: I added that markup after 4 items of the first row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding clearfix divs as explained [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) helped to resolve the display issues.

Fix applicable in my scenario was  adding `<div class="clearfix"></div>` after the four items of the first row